# Spring Security Default Endpoints

Tags: spring-security

How many Http endpoints are available on Spring Security by default?

I am aware of /OAuth and /Authorize but there could be more.

Is there a Swagger document on all the endpoints exposed by Spring Security. Where can I find the Swagger JSON file?

Comment: By default there are no endpoints. Everything depends on what configuration you are using.

Comment: So what are all the options for configuration and the corresponding endpoints?

Comment: I was hoping you would expand your question with more information about what you are using. But I can tell you that there is no Swagger document... most of Spring Security URL's are a bit special because they do not act as standard endpoints, but are rather request interceptors acting on a a defined URL (e.g. https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html).

Comment: What do you exactly need? Hiding the spring security default end point from swagger-ui or something else?

Comment: I want to expose all the end-points of Spring Security using Swagger.

Comment: You can try this `new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())`